# Force SSL on Rack::Static website

Tags: ruby, ssl, rack

How can I force SSL on [`Rack::Static` website?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby)

This is literally the entire codebase:

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gem [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer)

Add these lines, it will [automatically](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/blob/c131ab69f3112a05eee3596994a8d68ad493192a/lib/rack/ssl-enforcer.rb#L90-L94) direct from http to https.

```
 require 'rack/ssl-enforcer'
 use Rack::SslEnforcer
```